# Enlarging windows

Tags: window

I can't seem to enlarge my application windows by dragging them up to the toolbar. And I can't even make them minimize to half of the screen when you drag them to the bottom right or left. It's the same function as Windows 7.

Is there any way to enable this again? I had it working on the previous version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this shortcut key combinations:

`Ctrl` + `Super` + `Right Arrow`   Snaps window to the right half of your screen.

`Ctrl` + `Super` + `Left Arrow`   Snaps window to the left half of your screen.

`Ctrl` + `Super` + `Up Arrow`   Maximizes window.

`Ctrl` + `Super` + `Down Arrow`   Unmaximizes window.